# Why the debug option in VS editor is not working properly

Tags: javascript, editor

Just installed VS code VER 1.70 (Ubuntu OS) and got through this suggested basics https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/basics
Like in the introduction I made my first code lines and want to debug the written code.
My questions are:
Why my debug option isn't working?
How can I make it work?
I have followed step by step as introduced in the video.
Also, it was noted that no previous settings were needed.
Just:    Download the vs code – Done
Install the vs code – Done
Write the code lines – Done
Run the debug – NOT WORKING

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

First, click left line you want to pause.

[image: Debug breakpoint]

After that, press `F5` and choose `Node.js` for starting debug. If you see that, debug is running.

[image: Debug Tab]